# Run command to open command prompt as administrator

Tags: shortcut

how to open a command prompt as administrator using Run?Can any help me to open Command prompt in administrator using run command?

Comment: Please explain a bit clearer what you want

Answer (score 4):

**1) Create a shortcut:** Right-click on your desktop (or elsewhere) to create a link („New Shortcut“). Aka a .lnk file with an exceptionally well hidden extension. (Note: right-click-dragging from `System32/cmd.exe` is strangely not going to work, regarding the admin rights later on).

[image: create a shortcut]

**2) Enter Location** *( /k and what follows is just optional inspiration, if you like a directory switch and listing to start with)*

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k "cd D:\depot\pathOfYourLiking & dir /B"
```

[image: enter path]

**3) Name shortcut**. let say... admin-prompt

[image]

**4) admin properties:** Open admin-prompt(.lnk) file properties , Shortcut Tab, Advanced:

```
[x] Run as administrator
```

[image: Run as administrator]

**5) Copy the generated admin-prompt² into a directory**, somewhere in your path. (C:\Windows\System32, if you are out of inspiration)

(²strictly speaking it's `admin-prompt.lnk`, but that extension is a known executable extension, just like bat or cmd, so it may be ommited when calling this shortcut).

**6) Here you go :-)**

<kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>: admin-prompt

[image: admin prompt]

**7) Optional :** Revisit the properties of your admin-prompt Link, colors tab and style the background to a mild red, so you can distinguish regular and admin prompts on your screen... (lenght, buffer, font-size, and so on.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows 8 just right-click the start button and then click 'Command Prompt (Admin)'. That will open a command shell for you with admin rights.

From code you can use Process class:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe");
```

For this to work with admin credentials, you have to run your application with admin rights.

Comment: Yep.I tried using that it is working But i need to install the exe using code.So i need the Run command?

Comment: So you need to start a console with admin rights from code?

Comment: Yes i need to start from console

Answer (score 0):

Type in

```
RunAs.exe /user:adminUser "cmd.exe"
```

into the run dialog, replacing adminUser with your admin user credentials. RunAs will prompt you for the admin user password. Enter that, and the command windows opens up!

Comment: I tried but i when i type my password and press enter means the cmd closes?

Comment: You sure you have the right password? The error message disappears pretty quickly. So try this - 1. Open up the run dialog and type cmd.exe, 2. type in RunAs.exe /user:adminUser "cmd.exe" into the command window just opened. 3. Now type in your password and you'll be better able to see any error messages. After fixing that, you can run RunAs.exe /user:admin "cmd.exe" directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Windows PowerShell](http://www.7tutorials.com/simple-questions-what-powershell-what-can-you-do-it) command `Start-Process cmd -Verb runAs`  as `powershell.exe`'s argument in `Run`.

Type in Run: `powershell Start-Process cmd -Verb runAs`

**From [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) and [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)**

> [**Start-Process**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx)
>
> Detailed Description
>
> Starts one or more processes on the local computer.
>
> To specify the program that runs in the process, enter an executable file or script file, or a file that can be opened by using a program on the computer. If you specify a non-executable file, `Start-Process` starts the program that is associated with the file, much like the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet.
>
> You can use the parameters of `Start-Process` to specify options, such as loading a user profile, starting the process in a new window, or using alternate credentials.
>
> **[-Verb](http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)**
>
> `-Verb string`
>
> A verb to be used when starting the process, such as Edit, Open, or Print.
>          Each File type has a set of verbs that you can use.
>
> > Some common verbs are:
> >
> > ```
> >         .cmd  Edit, Open, Print, Runas
> >         .exe  Open, RunAs 
> >         .txt  Open, Print, PrintTo
> >         .wav  Open, Play
> > ```
>
> To find the verbs that can be used with the process, use the Verbs property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

So some of these don't solutions don't work with Windows 10 & 11, some were always plain bad solutions, and some require you to enter an administrator password, which you may, or may not have.

Under standard desktop circumstances — ***e.g.*** *on a machine that hasn't been set up for any special circumstance, like a machine that is part of a larger LAN, such as a School, or a Large Corporation* — you can preform the following method, and it should provide you with the very exact thing that the question is asking for (despite being nearly 7 years old now).

###### 1. Use the keybinding:

- #### <kbd>WIN</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>

---

###### 2. The Windows `Run` box should open, once you see it, type the text next to the bullet below into the text-input box.

- ##### `cmd.exe`

---

###### 3. After you type `cmd.exe` into the text-input, do not default to clicking the `ENTER` button, or pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. Rather than the using the sole <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you are going to instead *use the key-binding below*.

#### <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

You can check to ensure that your console is open with Administrative privileges by entering the following command:

---

#### `C:\...\...\> whoami /groups | findstr /b BUILTIN\`

This will be the output if you **"DO NOT"** have **Administrative Privileges**:

```
BUILTIN\Administrators               Alias            S-1-5-32-544 
                                       Group used for deny only

BUILTIN\Performance Log Users        Alias            S-1-5-32-559
                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group

BUILTIN\Users                        Alias            S-1-5-32-545                                                                                                 
                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

---

##### NOTE: The difference is in the line for the group `BUILTIN\Administrators`. Notice that the one below says enabled, and the one up-top says denied?

This will be the output if you do have **Administrative Privileges**:

---

```
BUILTIN\Administrators               Alias      S-1-5-32-544                                                                                                 
                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner

BUILTIN\Performance Log Users        Alias      S-1-5-32-559                                                                                                 
                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group  

BUILTIN\Users                        Alias      S-1-5-32-545                                                                                                                        
                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

---